# Как вывести прогноз многомерного временного ряда?

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение

Задавал тут вопрос по accyracy.
И вот теперь проблемка с predict.
если я вызываю предикт, то модель показывает данные последнего дня.
А вот как реализовать прогноз на следующий день и через день.
Вроде с одномерными временными рядами разобрался , а вот с многомерными не понимаю.
код прогноз загрязнения в пекине. стандартная нс.

'''

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM


# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j + 1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j + 1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j + 1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg

# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:, 4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:, 4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)
# drop columns we don't want to predict
reframed.drop(reframed.columns[[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(reframed.head())

# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=54, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2)                    
#
plot history
pyplot.subplot(211)
pyplot.title('Loss')
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[2]))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:, 0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:, 0]
# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

'''
Данные

'''

```
date    pollution   dew temp    press   wnd_dir wnd_spd snow    rain
2010-01-02  129.0   -16 -4.0    1020.0  SE  1.79    0   0
2010-01-03  148.0   -15 -4.0    1020.0  SE  2.68    0   0
2010-01-04  159.0   -11 -5.0    1021.0  SE  3.57    0   0
'''
```

9 столбцов.

**нужно чтобы был прогноз на следующий день и через день.**
А у меня получается только последнего дня(то есть нет прогноза).
как быть?
Есть данная НС.
Она стандартная, на ней отрабатываются прогнозирование на многомерных временных рядов.
Но как вывести сам прогноз. не понятно.
Прогноз на один день вперед, на основе обучения.
Прогноз на два дня вперед с разрывом(то есть прогноз в будущее через один день)
нарисовать тоже не пойму как. Т.к. там многомерный временной ряд.

Comment: Код длинный, разбираться лениво. Вы как тренируете сетку, какая у вас схема? Тут лучше рисовать, видимо, потому что на пальцах сложно объяснять. И сильно ещё зависит от того, за какой период у вас данные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.